# How can i compare mutlile timeranges and display them side by side in Android Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, schedule

I am trying to build a custom schedule with a custom layout in android compose.
I am using a wrapper object to handle the data of the events. Each event has a start and a end LocalDateTime.
When events are not colliding, the code works fine, but I need to a way to display multiple events side by side.
Do you have any ideas?

Code of Composable.

```
@Composable
fun BasicSchedule(
    bookings: List<Booking> = mainViewModel.listOfBookings,
    modifier: Modifier,
    currentSelectedDay: LocalDate = mainViewModel.currentSelectedDay,
    hourHeight: Dp = 64.dp,
) {
    val dividerColor = if (MaterialTheme.colors.isLight) Color.LightGray else Color.DarkGray
    var height = 0

    Layout(content = {
        bookings.sortedBy(Booking::startTimestamp).forEach { booking ->
            if (mainViewModel.currentSelectedDay == booking.startTimestamp.toJavaLocalDateTime()
                    .toLocalDate()
            ) {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.eventData(booking)) {
                    BookingViewComposable(booking = booking)
                }
            }
        }
    }, modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .drawBehind {
            repeat(23) {
                drawLine(
                    dividerColor,
                    start = Offset(0f, (it + 1) * hourHeight.toPx()),
                    end = Offset(size.width, (it + 1) * hourHeight.toPx()),
                    strokeWidth = 1.dp.toPx()
                )
            }
        }
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onLongPress = { offset ->
                mainViewModel.newBookingStartTime = offset.y
                    .div(height / 24)
                    .roundToInt()
                mainViewModel.createNewBookingDialogOpen = true
            })
        }) { measureables, constraints ->
        height = hourHeight.roundToPx() * 24
        val placeablesWithEvents = measureables.map { measurable ->
            val booking = measurable.parentData as Booking
            val eventDurationMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
                booking.startTimestamp.toJavaLocalDateTime(),
                booking.endTimestamp.toJavaLocalDateTime()
            )
            val eventHeight = ((eventDurationMinutes / 60f) * hourHeight.toPx()).roundToInt()
            val placeable = measurable.measure(Constraints.fixed(constraints.maxWidth - 30, eventHeight))

            Pair(placeable, booking)
        }
        
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, height) {
            placeablesWithEvents.forEach { (placeable, booking) ->
                val eventOffsetMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
                    LocalTime.MIN, booking.startTimestamp.toJavaLocalDateTime()
                )
                val eventY = ((eventOffsetMinutes / 60f) * hourHeight.toPx()).roundToInt()
                val eventX = 0

                placeable.place(eventX, eventY)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npMMD.png)
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS7fT.png)

Do you have any Suggestion?

I tried to compare the LocalDateTime Objects with each other, which was possible, but i have no idea how to do that with multiple DateTimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stack the events properly for every generalized edge-case would require a complex implementation, so here is a "simplified" one (in quotes because the solution to this problem is still non-trivial) that works well enough for cases where there are not too many overlapping events. This simplified implementation does not distribute the widths equally and simply lets the last element take some extra width in some edge-cases where width redistribution would be possible.

First I created a helper function for traversing graph-like data structures, since the code below is using it a few times in various ways. It returns a `Sequence` that can do breadth-first or depth-first traversal of a
sub-graph/sub-tree and yields the nodes in the order they are visited. In the implementation I only use the breath-first traversal, but I left the depth-first mode in the traverse function as well.

```kotlin
/**
 * Traverses the graph-like data structure starting from the receiver.
 * 
 * @param depthFirst if true, the traversal is depth-first, otherwise breadth-first
 * @param nextIterator a function that returns an iterator over the next nodes to visit
 * @return a sequence of nodes in the order they are visited
 */
fun <T> T.traverse(depthFirst: Boolean = false, nextIterator: (T) -> Iterator<T>): Sequence<T> {
    return sequence {
        val current = this@traverse
        if (!depthFirst) yield(current)

        val iterator = nextIterator(current)
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            yieldAll(iterator.next().traverse(depthFirst, nextIterator))
        }

        if (depthFirst) yield(current)
    }
}
```

For the data structure I used a `Node` class that can hold an element, knows its own depth inside the graph, knows the total depth of the graph it is part of and can hold references to both previous and next nodes.

```kotlin
class Node(
        val element: T,
        val currentDepth: Int,
        var totalDepth: Int = currentDepth + 1,
        val prev: MutableList<Node> = mutableListOf(),
        val next: MutableList<Node> = mutableListOf(),
    ) {
        var nextDepth: Node? = null
        var visualDebug = ""
    }
```

I also left in the code the `visualDebug` field that you can see in the code above. This debug info shows which elements (events) are affected by different parts of the algorithm. Right now the code just sets `visualDebug` to numbers 1-4 based on the cases described below, that are marked (1.) - (4.), but if you want to explore how the algorithm works, you can add your own debug info to this field at various steps inside the algorithm code. You can simply enable or disable this extra debug info by changing the value of `showVisualDebug` in the demo code that is available at the end of this post and [this UI should show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1CWU.jpg).

```kotlin
// set to true to see some debug info directly on each event
const val showVisualDebug = true
```

The simplified algorithm that I implemented goes as follows:

- Sort the elements using the comparator, this simplifies the already-simplfied approach a bit more

```kotlin
val sortedElements = elements.sortedWith(comparator)
```

- Create an empty list to hold the top-most (left-most) non-overlapping nodes of each graph

```kotlin
val nonOverlappingNodes = mutableListOf<Node>()
```

- Iterate through the sorted elements and add them to a graph-like data structure. Start by finding the first overlapping node in the last graph created so far.

```kotlin
sortedElements.forEach { elementToInsert ->
    val currentOverlappingWith = { node: Node -> areOverlapping(node.element, elementToInsert) }

    val last = nonOverlappingNodes.lastOrNull()

    val firstOverlap = last
        ?.traverse { it.next.iterator() }
        ?.firstOrNull(currentOverlappingWith)
    
    // ...
}
```

- If the element:

  - (1.) does not overlap with any of the nodes in the graph, start a new graph by creating a new node with this element at depth 0

```kotlin
if (firstOverlap == null) {
    // inserting a new non-overlapping node
    val node = Node(elementToInsert, currentDepth = 0)
    node.visualDebug = "1"
    nonOverlappingNodes.add(node)
}
```

- (2.) overlaps with a node that is not at depth 0, create a new node at depth 0 and connect it to the overlapping node

```kotlin
if (firstOverlap == null) { /* ... */ }
else if (firstOverlap.currentDepth > 0) {
    val node = Node(elementToInsert, currentDepth = 0, totalDepth = firstOverlap.totalDepth)
    node.visualDebug = "2"

    firstOverlap.prev.add(node)
    node.next.add(firstOverlap)
    node.nextDepth = firstOverlap

    // inserting a new top node at depth 0 that has an overlap deeper down the hierarchy
    nonOverlappingNodes.add(node)
}
```

- (3.) overlaps with a node at depth 0, find the first empty gap in this graph and create a new node at depth of the gap, then find the next overlapping node, if it exists, and connect the two (4.).

```kotlin
if (firstOverlap == null) { /* ... */ }
else if (firstOverlap.currentDepth > 0) { /* ... */ }
else {
    // insert an overlapping node at a deeper depth into the first overlap-free gap
    val overlap = last
        .traverse { it.next.iterator() }
        .fold(null as Node?) { lastOverlap, next ->
            val adjacent = lastOverlap == null || lastOverlap.currentDepth + 1 == next.currentDepth
            if (adjacent && currentOverlappingWith(next)) next else lastOverlap
        }!!

    // create the new node at the depth of the insertion
    val node = Node(elementToInsert, currentDepth = overlap.currentDepth + 1)
    node.totalDepth = overlap.totalDepth.coerceAtLeast(node.totalDepth)
    node.visualDebug = "3"

    // check if there is an overlap deeper down the hierarchy
    val nextOverlap = overlap
        .traverse { it.next.iterator() }
        .firstOrNull { it !== overlap && currentOverlappingWith(it) }
    if (nextOverlap != null) {
        node.visualDebug = "4"

        // remove the direct connection between overlap and nextOverlap if it exists
        overlap.next.remove(nextOverlap)
        nextOverlap.prev.remove(overlap)

        // add the direct connection between the new node and the next overlap
        nextOverlap.prev.add(node)
        node.next.add(nextOverlap)
        node.nextDepth = nextOverlap
        node.totalDepth = nextOverlap.totalDepth
    }

    // add the connection between overlap and the new node
    node.prev.add(overlap)
    overlap.next.add(node)
    
    // ... (there is a bit more code, see in the full code below)
}
```

- When all elements have been added to the graph(s), then the code traverses all graphs and calls the `factory` function for every graph node, passing the element, start weight, end weight and overlap count to the call. The `factory` function is responsible for creating the result that should be returned instead of the nodes.

```kotlin
val visited = mutableSetOf<Node>()
return nonOverlappingNodes.flatMap { node: Node ->
    node.traverse { it.next.iterator() }
        .filter(visited::add) // only process each node once
        .map {
            val startWeight = it.currentDepth / it.totalDepth.toFloat()
            val endWeight = (it.nextDepth?.currentDepth ?: it.totalDepth) / it.totalDepth.toFloat()
            factory(it.element, startWeight, endWeight, it.totalDepth, it.visualDebug)
        }
}
```

I also defined a `Booking` class and an `EventData` class to create a small usage demo.

```kotlin
data class Booking(
    val startTimestamp: LocalDateTime,
    val endTimestamp: LocalDateTime,
) {
    val duration = Duration.between(startTimestamp, endTimestamp)

    companion object {
        fun areOverlapping(a: Booking, b: Booking): Boolean {
            return a.startTimestamp < b.endTimestamp && b.startTimestamp < a.endTimestamp
        }
    }
}

data class EventData(
    val booking: Booking, val startWeight: Float, val endWeight: Float, val overlapCount: Int,
    val visualDebug: String,
) : ParentDataModifier {
    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?) = this@EventData
}
```

This is how it is used at the call-site:

```kotlin
val bookings: List<Booking> // = ...

val events = remember(bookings) {
    bookings.splitHierarchically(
        comparator = compareBy(Booking::startTimestamp).thenByDescending(Booking::duration),
        areOverlapping = Booking::areOverlapping,
        factory = { booking, startWeight, endWeight, overlapCount, visualDebug ->
            EventData(booking, startWeight, endWeight, overlapCount, visualDebug)
        },
    )
}
```

And this is how the event data is then used when creating the layout

```kotlin
    // ...
    val eventWidth = ((eventData.endWeight - eventData.startWeight) * availableWidth).roundToInt()
    val placeable = measurable.measure(Constraints.fixed(eventWidth, eventHeight))

    // ...
    val eventX = (eventData.startWeight * availableWidth).roundToInt()
    placeable.place(eventX, eventY)
```

---

### Full code

Copy the entire code below into an empty Kotlin file, open it in the IDE and check the Compose Preview window. [This UI should show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1CWU.jpg).

You can also call the `OverlappingScheduleUI` composable from your main `Activity` to run the example code.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ParentDataModifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

// set to true to see some debug info directly on each event
const val showVisualDebug = true

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun OverlappingScheduleUI() {
    val bookings: List<Booking> = LocalDateTime.parse("2023-04-28T08:00:00").let { base ->
        listOf(
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(  0), base.plusMinutes(  0 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes( 10), base.plusMinutes( 10 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes( 20), base.plusMinutes( 20 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes( 30), base.plusMinutes( 30 + 90)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes( 50), base.plusMinutes( 90 + 120)),

            Booking(base.plusMinutes( 90), base.plusMinutes( 90 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(100), base.plusMinutes(100 + 60)),

            Booking(base.plusMinutes(160), base.plusMinutes(160 + 90)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(170), base.plusMinutes(170 + 45)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(230), base.plusMinutes(230 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(230), base.plusMinutes(230 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(230), base.plusMinutes(230 + 60)),

            Booking(base.plusMinutes(300), base.plusMinutes(300 + 60)),
            Booking(base.plusMinutes(320), base.plusMinutes(320 + 60)),
        )
    }

    val events = remember(bookings) {
        bookings.splitHierarchically(
            comparator = compareBy(Booking::startTimestamp).thenByDescending(Booking::duration),
            areOverlapping = Booking::areOverlapping,
            factory = { booking, startWeight, endWeight, overlapCount, visualDebug ->
                EventData(booking, startWeight, endWeight, overlapCount, visualDebug)
            },
        )
    }

    Layout(content = {
        val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")
        events.forEach { event ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .then(event)
                .background(color = Color(0f, 0.5f, 1f - event.startWeight * 0.6f))) {
                Column {
                    if (showVisualDebug) Text(event.visualDebug, color = Color.White)
                    Text(event.booking.startTimestamp.format(dateTimeFormatter), color = Color.White)
                }
            }
        }
    }) { measureables, constraints ->
        val hourHeight = 64.dp
        val availableWidth = constraints.maxWidth

        val placeablesWithEvents = measureables.map { measurable ->
            val eventData = measurable.parentData as EventData
            val booking = eventData.booking
            val eventDurationMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
                booking.startTimestamp,
                booking.endTimestamp
            )
            val eventHeight = ((eventDurationMinutes / 60f) * hourHeight.toPx()).roundToInt()
            val eventWidth = ((eventData.endWeight - eventData.startWeight) * availableWidth).roundToInt()
            val placeable = measurable.measure(Constraints.fixed(eventWidth, eventHeight))

            Pair(placeable, eventData)
        }

        layout(availableWidth, hourHeight.roundToPx() * 24) {
            placeablesWithEvents.forEach { (placeable, eventData) ->
                val booking = eventData.booking
                val eventOffsetMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(
                    LocalTime.MIN, booking.startTimestamp
                )
                val eventY = ((eventOffsetMinutes / 60f) * hourHeight.toPx()).roundToInt()
                val eventX = (eventData.startWeight * availableWidth).roundToInt()

                placeable.place(eventX, eventY, eventData.startWeight)
            }
        }
    }
}

data class Booking(
    val startTimestamp: LocalDateTime,
    val endTimestamp: LocalDateTime,
) {
    val duration = Duration.between(startTimestamp, endTimestamp)

    companion object {
        fun areOverlapping(a: Booking, b: Booking): Boolean {
            return a.startTimestamp < b.endTimestamp && b.startTimestamp < a.endTimestamp
        }
    }
}

data class EventData(
    val booking: Booking, val startWeight: Float, val endWeight: Float, val overlapCount: Int,
    val visualDebug: String,
) : ParentDataModifier {
    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?) = this@EventData
}

/**
 * Traverses the graph-like data structure starting from the receiver.
 *
 * @param depthFirst if true, the traversal is depth-first, otherwise breadth-first
 * @param nextIterator a function that returns an iterator over the next nodes to visit
 * @return a sequence of nodes in the order they are visited
 */
fun <T> T.traverse(depthFirst: Boolean = false, nextIterator: (T) -> Iterator<T>): Sequence<T> {
    return sequence {
        val current = this@traverse
        if (!depthFirst) yield(current)

        val next = nextIterator(current)
        while (next.hasNext()) {
            yieldAll(next.next().traverse(depthFirst, nextIterator))
        }

        if (depthFirst) yield(current)
    }
}

/**
 * Splits the collection into non-overlapping groups.
 * 
 * @param comparator a comparator that orders the elements in the collection supplied through the receiver
 * @param areOverlapping a function that returns `true` if the two elements are overlapping
 * @param factory a function that creates the result from the element, start weight, end weight and overlap count
 * @return a list of results that the [factory] creates over the collection of the input elements
 */
fun <T, R> Collection<T>.splitHierarchically(
    comparator: Comparator<T>,
    areOverlapping: (a: T, b: T) -> Boolean,
    factory: (element: T, startWeight: Float, endWeight: Float, overlapCount: Int, visualDebug: String) -> R,
): List<R> {
    val elements = this

    if (elements.isEmpty()) return emptyList()

    class Node(
        val element: T,
        val currentDepth: Int,
        var totalDepth: Int = currentDepth + 1,
        val prev: MutableList<Node> = mutableListOf(),
        val next: MutableList<Node> = mutableListOf(),
    ) {
        var nextDepth: Node? = null
        var visualDebug = ""
    }

    // Sorting the items with their comparator
    // ensures a deterministic insertion order chosen by the caller
    val sortedElements = elements.sortedWith(comparator)

    val nonOverlappingNodes = mutableListOf<Node>()
    
    // Iterate through the sorted items and add them to one of the graphs.
    // If two items are overlapping they are connected in the same graph
    sortedElements.forEach { elementToInsert ->
        val currentOverlappingWith = { e: Node -> areOverlapping(e.element, elementToInsert) }
        
        val last = nonOverlappingNodes.lastOrNull()

        val firstOverlap = last
            ?.traverse { it.next.iterator() }
            ?.firstOrNull(currentOverlappingWith)

        if (firstOverlap == null) {
            // inserting a new non-overlapping node
            val node = Node(elementToInsert, currentDepth = 0)
            node.visualDebug = "1"
            nonOverlappingNodes.add(node)
        } else if (firstOverlap.currentDepth > 0) {
            val node = Node(elementToInsert, currentDepth = 0, totalDepth = firstOverlap.totalDepth)
            node.visualDebug = "2"

            firstOverlap.prev.add(node)
            node.next.add(firstOverlap)
            node.nextDepth = firstOverlap

            // inserting a new top node at depth 0 that has an overlap deeper down the hierarchy
            nonOverlappingNodes.add(node)
        }
        else {
            // insert an overlapping node at a deeper depth into the first overlap-free gap
            val overlap = last
                .traverse { it.next.iterator() }
                .fold(null as Node?) { lastOverlap, next ->
                    val adjacent = lastOverlap == null || lastOverlap.currentDepth + 1 == next.currentDepth
                    if (adjacent && currentOverlappingWith(next)) next else lastOverlap
                }!!

            // create the new node at the depth of the insertion
            val node = Node(elementToInsert, currentDepth = overlap.currentDepth + 1)
            node.totalDepth = overlap.totalDepth.coerceAtLeast(node.totalDepth)
            node.visualDebug = "3"

            val nextOverlap = overlap
                .traverse { it.next.iterator() }
                .firstOrNull { it !== overlap && currentOverlappingWith(it) }
            if (nextOverlap != null) {
                node.visualDebug = "4"

                // remove the direct connection between overlap and nextOverlap if it exists
                overlap.next.remove(nextOverlap)
                nextOverlap.prev.remove(overlap)

                // add the direct connection between the new node and the next overlap
                nextOverlap.prev.add(node)
                node.next.add(nextOverlap)
                node.nextDepth = nextOverlap
                node.totalDepth = nextOverlap.totalDepth
            }

            // add the connection between overlap and the new node
            node.prev.add(overlap)
            overlap.next.add(node)

            // updating the nextDepth of the overlap if the new node is closer
            if (node.currentDepth < (overlap.nextDepth?.currentDepth ?: Int.MAX_VALUE)) {
                overlap.nextDepth = node
            }

            // propagate the total depth inside the current graph only
            val totalDepth = node.totalDepth           

            val visited = mutableSetOf(node)
            node.traverse {
                iterator {
                    yieldAll(it.prev.filter(visited::add))
                    yieldAll(it.next.filter(visited::add))
                }
            }.forEach {
                it.totalDepth = totalDepth
            }
        }
    }

    val visited = mutableSetOf<Node>()
    return nonOverlappingNodes.flatMap { node: Node ->
        node.traverse { it.next.iterator() }
            .filter(visited::add) // only process each node once
            .map {
                val startWeight = it.currentDepth / it.totalDepth.toFloat()
                val endWeight = (it.nextDepth?.currentDepth ?: it.totalDepth) / it.totalDepth.toFloat()
                factory(it.element, startWeight, endWeight, it.totalDepth, it.visualDebug)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have mostly no clue what your code is doing, but I was able to implement it in my project and I will take my time to understand whats going on. Luckily, the drag and drop features I implemented did not break.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @jmlinar That's great to hear. If any section of the explanation above is unclear or is missing details, let me know here in the comments and I can expand that part.